# 500 server error

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер, dle

Сделал сайт на dle. На локальном сервере он работал хорошо, но когда я поставил его на хост, перестали работать некоторые вещи: нельзя зайти в профиль (Выдает ***500 server error***), нельзя посмотреть все новости, не работает пару скриптов.

С чем это связано?

*P.S. искал решение в интернете, ничего не помогло (редактировал .htaccess, менял привилегии на файлы и папки)*

Comment: Смотрите логи веб сервера, там по 500 ошибкам обычно много интересного

Comment: @Mike , Я посмотрел логи и понял в чем дело. Допустим, когда пользователь пытается зайти на свой профиль, в строке пишется следующее: www.url.ru/ _user / username_ . Сервер пытается выдать файлы находящиеся в данном каталоге (_user / username_). И конечно же его там нет. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: вы видимо не перенесли .htaccess в котором были правила преобразования url

Comment: @Mike , Я переместил файлы моего сайта на сервер, со всеми .htaccess, ничего не удалял. Может я что-то не то сделал? На сервере есть папка _public_html_ , туда я залил все файлы своего сайта. Получается главный **.htaccess** должен лежать в _public_html_ ?